# Trying to get the sum of fields in a list of documents - dart:math

Tags: list, dart, sum

[image]

Here's what I've got so far which works (returns 6) if I set:

var list = [1, 2, 3]

Otherwise this is the error I have:

[image]

Totally new to dart and coding really but have had a dig and can't find an obvious answer.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Tried to return the sum of a list, worked when I set the list to 1, 2, 3 so thought it would work on a list of documents...

Comment: You fold with an initial value of type int, you cannot use the "+" between an int and a TotalMonthlyIncomeRecord. What's inside TotalMonthlyIncomeRecord?

Comment: TotalMonthlyIncomeRecord is a list of documents, basically I want the code to read the documents and sum all of the given values for a particular field. Is this even possible? Thanks for the response btw :)

Comment: What is a document for you? Do you have the class of TotalMonthlyIncomeRecord to show us? It will be a bit hard to help you without more information.

Comment: The list is a list of documents within firebase, all with one field with the name 'answer'. I want the code to query the documents and return all of the field values for this field called 'answer' then I need it to sum the values.